# Can't SSH on a FRESH install of Ubuntu Server 23.10 on a Raspberry

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, ubuntu-server

After days of trial and error, Ubuntu Server 23.10 is FINALLY running on my Pi.
Already ran `apt update` and `apt upgrade`. However I can only control my Pi via direct keyboard and monitor. It's not headless since it requires a monitor and can't SSH from my computer.

Currently the Pi is getting an IP address in the ranges of `127.0.0...` instead of `192.168....` . This is what the network map looks like (typical home setup):

Router -> Switch -> Pi with Ubuntu = IP range of `127.0.0...`

Router -> Computer = IP range of `192.168.0...`

How can I get around this hurdle and connect via ssh from my computer?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is localhost, if your RPi doesn’t have a 192.168.0.x address it means your DHCP server isn’t assigning one to it

Comment: It sounds like your pi doesn't have a connection to the local network, or it doesn't have an address on that network. It would be helpful if you could run "ip a" on the pi (to list all network interfaces) and [edit] your question to include the output. I realize copying information from the pi might be difficult.